# PHP exec $PATH variable missing elements

Tags: php, bash, path, environment-variables, exec

When I echo $PATH on my command line, it returns

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

When I execute this php code

```
exec('echo $PATH; whoami; less /etc/paths; 2>&1')
```

I get

```
string 'echo $PATH; whoami; less /etc/paths; 2>&1' (length=56)
array
  0 => string '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' (length=29)
  1 => string 'eric' (length=4)
  2 => string '/usr/bin' (length=8)
  3 => string '/bin' (length=4)
  4 => string '/usr/sbin' (length=9)
  5 => string '/sbin' (length=5)
  6 => string '/usr/local/bin' (length=14)
  7 => string '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin' (length=30)
  8 => string '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' (length=29)
```

This is on Mac OS X. Can anyone tell me why my last two path elements are missing?

Comment: Are you calling PHP within apache or in cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables on Mac OS X are set by differing mechanisms depending on how your code, or its parent process, was launched. To insure that items launched from an interactive shell and items launched by the WindowServer have the same path, you need to keep ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist in sync with what is set in .profile (or .cshrc).

Answer (score 13):

Try executing this before you call `exec`:

```
putenv("PATH=" .$_ENV["PATH"]. ':/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin');
```

Comment: if I use getenv("PATH"), it returns the proper path with my appending it.

Comment: For example, I just needed to do `putenv("PATH=" . getenv('PATH'));`

Answer (score 7):

What does:

```
php -r 'print getenv("PATH");'
```

give you?

It's likely the shell that PHP spawns (probably `sh` instead of `bash`) isn't getting the same environment that you have at the command line. You don't say how you're running your `exec` command.

This will show you which shell is being run:

```
php -r 'echo shell_exec("echo $0");'
```

You may need to use the `putenv` command or determine whether your path needs to be set in `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` in order for it to be picked up.

Comment: @Eric: Try setting and exporting `ENV` in the environment that you're running your script from (before you run it). For example: `export ENV=/etc/profile` or `export ENV=/home/username/.profile`. (If you use `/.bashrc`, you'll need to put code in it that prevents `sh` from running Bash-specific code that it can't understand.) The Bourne shell only sources those files automatically when it's a login shell.