# Apache ant working in root not in shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, ant, ssh, putty

i have a problem in Apache ant 
all commands are working in ssh client putty
but when i try to run in shell_exec it gives error

**`sh: ant: command not found`**

is there is any permission using in shell_exec

i have root access to the server

Comment: Does the user who runs the webserver has access to run ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does PHP honour your environment PATH? you may need to qualify the path to the executable. Refer to this post for more path/shell info: [PHP exec $PATH variable missing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements)

Comment: if you try running:
    exec('echo $PATH')

is the path to you ant executable there?

Comment: ant path is not there that is the response  /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: Did you fix this? You probably need to fully qualify the path to the ant executable in your shell_exec

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Feel free to accept this answer if your issue is resolved.