# How to set $PATH for php exec or shell_exec

Tags: php, ant, centos, exec, shell-exec

I have set the PATH to run ant and it is working on putty but on php exec it is returning sh ant command not found 
i have tried 
to set PATH by export PATH=/usr/ant/bin

Comment: why do you need that? if you use putty, stay on windows and be have fun!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10834134/127035?

Answer (score 6):

Call putenv before exec:

```
putenv('PATH=/usr/ant/bin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are set in the context of a user session. If you want to set the variable for the PHP user you should check what user apache runs under (typically apache), and add

`export PATH=/usr/ant/bin`

to

`/home/apache/.bashrc`

So that the path is set for every session the user `apache` starts.

Comment: in home there is no dir called apache can i create such a dir ?

Comment: yeah, that should be fine...you'll want to use `useradd` just make sure you apache user is in fact called 'apache'. what version of linux are you running? http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser