# Web script can't find installed package/software (CentOS)

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, centos

I'm pretty new to using SSH and such to install software. I'm trying to use https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader on my site (http://voddr.com/yt/index.php?id=yrreBFLghMc) but as you can see, it comes back with the error "You must have Ffmpeg installed in order to use this function."

I have installed ffmpeg, using Nux Desktop (see the guide I followed here: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos)

When typing "ffmpeg" into SSH it comes back with this, which must mean it is installed:

[image: command: ffmpeg]

Also, I tried the command "which ffmpeg", which returned the path of ffmpeg: "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"

`php-yt_downloader` uses `which ffmpeg` to detect whether it is installed, and if not, it returns the error "You must have Ffmpeg installed in order to use this function." - but if I'm able to use it fine from my SSH window, why can't the script detect it?

All I'm wondering, is there something else I must do when installing software to allow a domain to use it (like install the software in the domain's path?), or is this entirely a problem with the `php-yt_downloader` resource? I'm using CentOS 7 and Plesk web panel.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done everything right installing the software. I would check your php environment. Have a look at this link [from the php manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

> Note:
>   The backtick operator is disabled when safe mode is enabled or shell_exec() is disabled.

I would first try the easy example on the manual page to check if the *backtick operator* works. It could be that your webserver setup does not allow shell execution and this is what yt_downloader is using, see [their source code.](https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader/blob/master/youtube-dl.class.php#L650)

Comment: Hmm, this works fine. It outputs the files in the web directory along with some other info. Weird

Comment: So what is the output if you change in that page $output = \`ls -al\`; to $output = \`which ffmpeg\`; And double check if in the yt_downloader code there are really backticks - somtimes copy and pasting can cause trouble with these backticks.

Comment: It doesn't output anything when I change it to `which ffmpeg`... So that means it doesn't have permission? Or it simply didn't find it?

Comment: strange, so try \`set\`and look in the output for path - is there /usr/bin listed? And what do you get with \`/usr/bin/ffmpeg\` - if you get the same output as in the shell you will have to somehow provide the path to the ffmpeg prog in the config of yt_downloader. Or you'll have to provide /usr/bin to the path variable for the script , see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835923/how-to-set-path-for-php-exec-or-shell-exec?rq=1