# Call php exec function on linux

Tags: php, linux, xampp, exec

Few months ago I make small c++ console application on Windows. I need to run exe file over the browser. I use exec php function and everything works fine. Now I trying to do same thing on Linux so that I can put executable file on Linux web server. My linux executable file (inpainting) work when is called from console. But I can't run executable file over exec function.

**xampp windows:** - this works, i get my results.

```
<?php
$imagename = $_GET['imagename'];
exec('inpainting.exe' .$imagename); 
echo "<img src=\"./images/img-uploads/ob_img$imagename.jpg\" />";
?>
```

But how to run it on xampp linux? I try this and results is blank screen.

```
<?php
$imagename = $_GET['imagename'];
exec('inpainting' .$imagename); 
echo "<img src=\"./images/img-uploads/ob_img$imagename.jpg\"/>";
?>
```

And I try few more things, but nothing happens. Some people say that exec is bad thing, if someone have other better solution - please share with me. Any ideas? Tnx

*I allow all permissions on working folders. I run xampp 1.7.3a on Ubuntu 12.4*

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the executable in exec?

Comment: you need a space between the program and the filename, probably what @Michael said would help too.

Comment: Linux can't run Windows' executables.  Also, there's a **huge** security hole there.

Comment: it could be a linux version of the software...

Comment: @RyanNaddy "Few months ago I make small c++ console application on Windows."  Sounds like he might have uploaded the binary....

Comment: @Corbin "My linux executable file (inpainting) work when is called from console."

Comment: check PATH variable used by PHP 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements

Comment: @AlexLunix Odd he gave it a `.exe` though.  Sounds like it might be two different files.  (Probably not though -- I must admit that I tuned out a bit after reading the first sentence, seeing `exe` and looking at the code.)

Comment: @Corbin Completely valid point though, if they are the same file, that would definitely be a problem.

Comment: @Michael - Yes, I try and nothing...

Comment: No, i have to different files. inpainting.exe is for windows, and inpainting is for linux

Comment: How come no one ever looks at their web server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help, I added the second parameter then did a dump, it should display all the output from the command that was run.

```
<?php
$imagename = $_GET['imagename'];
exec('inpainting ' .$imagename, $opt); 
var_dump($opt);
echo "<img src=\"./images/img-uploads/ob_img$imagename.jpg\"/>";
```

Comment: I try that, but instead of image I got this: `array(0) { } `

Comment: @Rile I see that you've accepted this as an answer. I'm facing a similar problem. Could you explain how you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: I not fixed my problem :( sorry