# Nginx/PHP-FPM exec another php script

Tags: php, ubuntu, chmod, user-permissions, chown

This works, so exec function is not disabled.

```
exec('ls');
```

This doesn't work even thought script.php has 777 chmod.

```
exec('php script.php');
```

This doesn't work either.

```
exec('php -v');
```

I tried to chmod and chown /var/www/ folder, but it doesn't help.
I suppose this is due to the www-data user permissions, looks like it doesn't have access to several bin files.

How can I solve this?

Comment: is php in the path? maybe you need to do something like `/usr/bin/php` or wherever it's located

Comment: why would you use exec to execute a php script within a php file? Why not use `include`?

Comment: Yes, PHP is in the path: /opt/php5/bin/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
which php
```

and then get the path and put it in exec() like

```
exec("/opt/local/bin/php -v");
```

Comment: It works! Thank you :) ... but I can't understand why it works like this?

Comment: it didn't work because the php executable it not added to the path for the user that php-fpm run with or nginx :) this is why you need to use the absolute path

Comment: I get this message: "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes". Be patient :)

Comment: Is there a way to add the script to www-data user's path?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements :)

Answer (score -2):

try `php -f script.php`

Im not 100% sure this is correct, but i've always sent the -f flag when passing in a file.

Comment: -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>. This is already self explanatory !

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the part about php -v not working either. I was just answering the `php script.php` part.