# Calling ansi2html.sh from php exec gives gawk error on OSX

Tags: php, macos, bash, pipe, gawk

I'm trying to get formatted coloured output from a command line utility presented on a php web page.

I'm using ansi2html.sh from http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh

It works fine if I run the same command from the command line. I am on OSX.

The command I am running is:

```
exec ("vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development | ../../phinx_upgrades/ansi2html.sh 2>&1", $phinx_output, $phinx_return);
```

The output I get is:

```
../../phinx_upgrades/ansi2html.sh: line 38: gawk: command not found
```

So I assume its running the script, but it cant find gawk. I did `brew install gawk` but its already installed.

I can run gawk from command line, `gawk --version` gives me `GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1`

If I ask `which gawk` I get `/usr/local/bin/gawk`

When I `echo  $PATH` I see `/usr/local/bin` as one of my paths.

Comment: What is one line 38 ?What happens if you just run `gawk --version`

Comment: I get: ```GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1``` plus GNU blurb

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with `OSX`, but i think that you have to add `gawk` folder to your environment variable `PATH`
Also, check directly on your bash if you can launch `gawk`, if it is work fine in your bash, so restart your Apache server

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks I added new info based on your suggestions.

Comment: @Adamski have you restarted your Apache Server ?

Comment: yes I did restart Apache... I am using MAMP locally for PHP development.

Answer (score 1):

Answer [PHP exec $PATH variable missing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements) should give hints for setting up the right $PATH for the php call.  As a quick fix you could edit the ansi2html.sh script to reference /usr/local/bin/gawk directly