# call ffmepg from apache php without full path

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I need a apache /php  to recognize ffmpeg command without specifing the full bath of  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

calling ffmpeg from command line executes the program
calling ffmpeg from php via web does not execute the program 
calling /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  from php via web does execute the program

why:
a php script calls youtube-dl (a compiled program)  and executes ffmpeg internally

thank you in advance - 
tried ffmpeg path:
    which ffmpeg
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin


#php code for testing:
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg 2>&1');
echo "shell exec /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg <pre>$output</pre>";
#Response:
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright #(good)

#Second php code for testing:
$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg 2>&1');
echo "shell exec <pre>$output</pre>";
#Response:
sh: ffmpeg: command not found #(bad)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses default `profile` to execute commands with [`backticks`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)/`shell_exec`. It apparently does not include `/usr/local/bin` in the `$PATH`. To fix the problem you might explicitly add `/usr/local/bin` to your default path:

```
sudo echo '$PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/php_needed.sh
```

In modern systems the whole content of `/etc/profile.d` folder will be included in the profile.

Comment: thank you i ran that command, along with updatedb, hash -r restarted httpd  and php/apache still says ffmpeg command not found

Comment: the contents of /etc/profile.d/php_needed.sh are $PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Comment: Well, it always worked for me, sorry for misleading you. Try these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements

Comment: thank you putenv("PATH=" .$_ENV["PATH"]. ':/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin');  how can i thank u more

Comment: sorry one more question - thank you - before  this i srewed up my $path stuff trying different things - when i login to to ssh via putty with root i get 
Last login: Sat Feb 14 05:25:58 2015 from 10.10.10.101
-bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin: No such file or directory
that never showed up how do i get rid of it ? and restore the path back to default

Comment: Put `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` as the very last string in your `/etc/profile` file. This should help.