# PHP ignores some directories in PATH

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute a .exe file form PHP.

I've set the PATH variable and confirmed that it works by running my command from random directory.

PHP code:

```
$command = "myCommand >> log.txt 2>&1";
echo exec($command, $output, $return)."<br>";
```

I've inspected the log.txt and it contains an error:

```
'myCommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What could be the reason for this issue? it seems that PHP won't look into all directories specified inside of PATH. What do you recommend that I do?

Specifying full path to `myCommand` works, but I'd like to omit it. I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Which OS are you using? There is at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements which explains this behavior.

Comment: I am using windows.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(getenv("PATH"));` and how does it relate to your configured PATH variable of your OS?

Comment: Hm. It is missing the folder in which myCommand.exe is stored. This further proves that something funky is going on with php.

Comment: How do you run the PHP script? Do you run it manually in a Command Prompt or is it executed automatically by the web server?

Comment: When have you added the directory of your "myCommand.exe" file to your PATH variable? Have you restarted the web server? Have you restarted the shell which runs the PHP script? Have you restarted the  OS?

Comment: @Progman restarting the OS is not needed and the first question is not "when" but "how".

Comment: PHP actually doesn't care too much about your `PATH`. As the [documentation of `exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-notes) explains, `exec()` starts the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) and passes to it the command line. It's the job of `cmd.exe` to find `myCommand` in `%PATH%` and start it. This is also visible from the error message (*"'myCommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*) that belongs to `cmd.exe`.